Total Effect, Substitution Effect, and Income Effect
We were given this information to compute the total, substitution, and income effects.
$U=7.5x^{0.3} \cdot 5y^{0.2}$,
$\text{Income} = 10,000$,
$P_x = 5$,
$P_y = 2.5$,
$P_{x'}=4$.
I am having a hard time trying to get the income and substitution effect.

Hi please show us your attempt first per our rules for homework questions

(I'll be using formulae from Hal Varian.)
Given, U(x,y)= 7.5 x^0.3 5y^0.2
Income (M) = 10000
Initial Price of good-x: 5
Price of good-y: 2.5 
New Price of good-x (Px'): 4

Solution:
This is clearly a Cobb Douglas Utility Function.
So, you could either derive demand curve for good-x using all the numbers given or directly put the value in the already derived demnd function of good-x.
The demand function for good-x is given by (it is independent of the coefficients of both the goods; you can check it by deriving the demand function);
x* = (a.M)/(a+b)Px

At Px= 5, a= 0.3, b= 0.2 and M=10000, we get that
   
x* = (0.3* 10000)/ (0.5*5)
              x* = 1200

In order to calculate the substitution effect, one first needs to calculate the change in income required to keep the original bundle just affordable. As price of only good-x has changed, the change in income is given by
Change in M= Change in price * (x*)
           = (-1)* (1200)
           = -1200

The new income, say M', is 10000 - 1200 = 8800

So, demand of good-x at new price and income level is x'(Px',M'):
              x' = (0.3*8800)/(0.5*4)
              x' = 1320

The substitution effect is
             x'(Px',M') - x*(Px,M)
           = 1320 - 1200 = 120

To calcuate income effect, the income is kept constant and new prices are taken into account such that demand for good-x is given by x''(Px',M)
Hence, demand for good-x at
Px' = 4 and M = 10000 is
                x'' = 0.3*10000/0.5*4
                    = 1500

The change in quantity demanded of good-x due to income effect is thus given by:
             x''(Px',M) - x'(Px',M')
             = 1500 - 1320
             = 180

Hence, total price effect is 120 + 180 = 300
